# How to post new records in sql in an existing table where my column has all NULL values?

Tags: mysql

I have added a new Column name *Age* in an existing table called *StudentRecords*. All the values are showing `Null` when I do `Select * From StudentRecords;`

How do I update so I can give a new age to a student in my table ?

`Alter Table StudentRecords Add Age varchar (40);`

Comment: Why is age a `VARCHAR(40)`? Are you expecting "older than dirt" to be a value? How is this age computed? Adding a column like that will leave the values `NULL` since you haven't populated them.

Comment: When you added the column you did not add a value. This is called DDL and DML. In your DDL you did not specify the value and did not explicitly say NOT NULL thus it is null.

Comment: Jay - Did my answer solve your problem? If so - please consider marking answer as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you wanted the column to not be null, or a default value for all *Age* column data, this is the way to do so in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE <YourTable> 
ADD <NewColumn> <NewColumnType> NOT NULL DEFAULT <DefaultValue>
```

So in your case, the above would be (if you wanted the records to not be `null`):

```
ALTER TABLE StudentRecords
ADD Age VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
```

If you wanted to change/modify an existing record though, here's the SQL code to do that (if you wanted to only alter the record with 4 as an `ID`:

```
UPDATE StudentRecords
SET Age = "This person is old"
WHERE ID = 4;
```